# Accessing array from JSON in if statement Node.JS

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, express, if-statement

My JSON file looks something like this

```
module.exports={
    roles: {
        valid:["Area Director","Managing Director","Default"]}}
```

And I'm trying to do this in my Node.js

```
connection.connect(function(err) {
  connection.query(`SELECT display_title FROM user WHERE username = "${rolecheckemail}" `, function (err, result, fields) {
  try{if(result[0].display_title.includes(roles.roles.valid)
    )
{
  res.send("Valid")}
  else{
    res.send("Not Valid")}
  }
  catch(err){
    res.send("Not Valid")
  }});
});
```

I want to check if my `display_title` includes any of the valid roles from the JSON.
My Node.js syntax seems to be wrong.

Comment: is display_title an array? Or want you to check if display_title is one of the roles.valid values?

Comment: display_title is a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few errors:

To declare an array you need to use coma and change the check for include:

```js
let valid = ["Area Director"||"Managing Director"|| "Default"]
console.log(valid) 
// you have created an array of 1 element cause of the OR condition: STRING_1 OR STRING_2 will return STRING_2

valid = ["Area Director", "Managing Director", "Default"]
console.log(valid)

const display_title = 'Area Director'
console.log(valid.includes(display_title))
```

Comment: dispal_title is already a defined string. What I want to do here is check that if it includes any of the entries from the JSON as substring or exact match.

Comment: please update your question with some text example because it is unclear to me what you want to archive

Comment: I've update the snippet, can you check now

Comment: I don't mean code, but text example.
Your code "translated" says: IF ( the string `display_title` CONTAINS an array of string) {} ,this will be always `false`

My code show you how to check: IF the `valid` array CONTAINS the string `display_title` return true

Comment: I understand your suggestion. But, what I want is that even if my `display_title= "Area Director - US"` it should be considered as valid.

Comment: You sir are a champion. It worked! I re-read your code!

Answer (score 0):

First of all i guess your JSON structure in not allowed, at least didn't worked for me.

Second instead of a JSON u can also use a .ts file, inside of it you can make 'const' variables with 'export', and import all around you application, like this.

```
export const data = {
    roles: {
        valid: [
            'Area Director',
            'Managing Director',
            'Default'
        ]
    }
};
```

Once you have you variables written, you just will need to import the ts into where you need it, like this.

```
import { data } from './MyDocument.ts';
```

In my case im using Angular 9, and i have needed to do the following.

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  public data: any = data;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.data.roles.valid[2] === 'Default') {
      console.log('Hello');
    }
  }
}
```

[Here is our 'Hello'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKU6P.png)

I just tried to help you out, if this didn't works for you, or you need more help, please, provide a code snippet, so i can figure out more accurately what's the problem.

Comment: I've fixed the JSON based on your suggestion. But, in `if(display_title.includes(roles.roles.valid))` I want to check my string "display_title" to have any of the roles from the JSON array valid and provide true

Comment: Then use 'in' e.g. public validData = ['Area Director',  'Managing Director', 'Default']; this array contains your valid data, then you need to check, the json against the valid data like this: if (display_title in roles.roles.valid) {}

Comment: This should work too, but if you look at the above solution it is also considering wildcard searches such as "Area Director - US" or "IN Area Director". And, that is the use case that I'm looking for exactly.